# Typescript interface template using keyof lookup

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want something like

```
interface Operation<T, K extends keyof T> {
  key: keyof T;
  operation: 'add' | 'remove';
  value: T[K];
}
```

but without requiring to pass the `K` as a template; basically, I want to be able to do:

```
interface User {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

// this is valid
const operation: Operation<User> = {
  key: 'name',
  operation: 'add',
  value: 'the value',
}
// this is valid
const operation: Operation<User> = {
  key: 'age',
  operation: 'add',
  value: 123,
}

// this is not valid
const operation: Operation<User> = {
  key: 'age',
  operation: 'add',
  value: '123',  // type is wrong, should be number
}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: This looks like you want type checking at runtime because at compile time there is no way of knowing what you are going to put in your "key", it does not seem doable.

Comment: Why would that be at runtime? How is this different than say doing it via a function call? You can have `const foo = <T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K): T[K] => obj[key];` and this is perfectly valid; doing `foo(user, 'name')` vs `foo(user, 'age')` would return the right type

Comment: There is a difference between type checking and returning the right type, it returns the type that was stored in the variable, but it does not do type checking appropriately at compile time, let's say in your foo example you did ```let key = 'a'``` ```key += 'ge'``` then called ```foo(user, key) / 1``` it would return the right result but type checking will scream because it does not know if T[key] is string or number at compile time

Comment: This article is relevant: https://medium.com/@nandiinbao/partial-type-argument-inference-in-typescript-and-workarounds-for-it-d7c772788b2e

Comment: @AlexWayne Can you make this an answer, please? Looks like a factory function like `const operation = makeOperation<User>('add')('age', 123)` could work.

Answer (score 0):

Personally we can if we refine the way of creating the object by using function. The idea is like below:

First of all, create the type getting value type of any property:

```js
type ValueType<T, K> = K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never;
```

Then define `Operation` type:

```js
type Operation<T, K> = {
  key: K
  operation: 'add' | 'delete'
  value: ValueType<T, K>
}
```

Now the key thing is here to define the build function instead of create the object directly since we're keen to read the argument:

```js
type BuildOperation<T> = <K>(arg: K) => (arg: Operation<T, K>) => Operation<T, K>


function build<T>(): BuildOperation<T> {
  return (key) => (props) => ({
    key,
    ...props,
  });  
}
```

Finally, we can use our function by setting key `as const` to make sure Typescript won't infer as string:

```js
type User = { name: string; age: number }

const obj = build<User>()('age' as const)({
  key: 'age',
  value: 20, // It will hint you this is number
  operation: 'add',
});
```

Comment: I think the whole purpose of OP's question is to not provide the key statically to the function or else it could have been done directly as a type parameter, which means that he wants it to be dynamic. Which is not possible because the values of variables can only be determined at runtime.

Comment: The key thing is here that we can take the argument name as const string literal type, then we can look up the type of that key in a specific type. That's useful technique as you want to lookup the type of any key

Answer (score -1):

```ts
interface Operation<T, K extends keyof T> {
  operation: "add" | "remove";
  value: T[K];
}

interface User {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

// this is valid
const operation1: Operation<User, "name"> = {
  operation: "add",
  value: "the value",
};

// this is valid
const operation2: Operation<User, 'age'> = {
  operation: "add",
  value: 123,
};

// this is not valid
const operation3: Operation<User, 'age'> = {
  operation: "add",
  value: "123", // type is wrong, should be number
};
```

I recommend use `keyof`.
but, I agree comments. Why is it needed? it not work on runtime application.
It just check when it is compiled.

Comment: Your `Operation` is missing the `key`

Comment: There's nothing in the question that suggests that OP is looking to do this check at runtime.

Comment: I agree with guys.
I want to say it is not needed,
At run time, TypeScript type errors have no meaning.

Comment: I think the whole purpose of OP's question is to not provide the key in the type, which means that he wants it to be dynamic. Which is not possible because the values of variables can only be determined at runtime.